# What can be passed in (void *)context?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewanimation

I'm doing some UIView animation stuff using

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
// ... Animation configuration ...
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationEnded:finished:context:)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Regarding the following question: [Apple rejected app because of animationDidStop:finished:context: is a non-public api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455604/apple-rejected-app-because-of-animationdidstopfinishedcontext-is-a-non-public)

I implemented my own method as the "setAnimationDidStopSelector".

My question is regarding the **context:(void *)context** parameter. Apple defines it as follow :

> Additional application-supplied
>   information that is passed to the
>   animation delegate messages—the
>   selectors set using the
>   setAnimationWillStartSelector: and
>   setAnimationDidStopSelector: methods.

I'm wondering what king of thing can be passed in as a context. I'm relatively new to Objective-C and C programming and a bit lost with the void* type.

Can we pass in any sort of argument, objects, NSDictionnary, NSString, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void *` is a pointer to anything. You can pass a pointer to any object or to other stuff such as a struct or a Core Foundation opaque type. To get rid of the compiler warning, cast the pointer to `void *`:

```
... context:(void *)myDictionary];
```

Be aware that the method has no idea what `context` contains and thus will not retain it or otherwise care for correct memory managemnet. You have to ensure that the thing you pass to `context` still exists when the animation delegate methods are called.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, this sounds clear and I just found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void/1304277#1304277

Answer (score 0):

```
context:(void *)myDictionary];
```

When calling this method and trying to pass

```
(void *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] -
```

xCode proposes to make some _bridge  because of invalid pointerCast from C to Objective-C ...