# Class method not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, parameters, selector

My program keeps crashing:

```
-(void) moveImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration curve:(int)curve    x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y key:(NSString *)key
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:)];

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
image.transform = transform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This gets called, and when finished i want it to call the method bellow:

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)key
{
if (key == @"burn") {
    //The burn card has been moved and stopped. Ready for the next.
    [self annPlayerRight];
}

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple rejected app because of animationDidStop:finished:context: is a non-public api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455604/apple-rejected-app-because-of-animationdidstopfinishedcontext-is-a-non-public)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yeah because `setAnimationDidStopSelector:withObject:` method does not exist...
UIView's actual method is :
`+ (void)setAnimationDidStopSelector:(SEL)selector`

(notice that the `withObject:` part is missing)

Comment: Thats what i thought, how would i send it parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Check [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for `setAnimationDidStopSelector` method.

> The message sent to the animation delegate after animations end. The default value is NULL. The selector should be of the form:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context.
```

So when you call `beginAnimations` there is parameter `context` that would be accessible in `animationDIdStop` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see but i am still confused, so its not possible to send a string as a parameter through: [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:)];

Comment: Right now no. You can send in beginAnimation through Context only.

Comment: Just asking what is the problem with `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];` sending parameter in context here ?